# Export public key from JKS and read from Java

Tags: java, openssl, rsa, jks

I've generated a RSA 256 public/private key in JKS format.

```
keytool -genkey -keyalg RSA -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -storepass password -validity 360 -keysize 10950
```

This file is configured in Keycloak, which would sign access tokens (JWT) with the private key.

From my Java based application, I would like to verify the signature of access token with the public key. Probably there exists a much simpler mechanism, but I'm confused after trying various methods.

Exported public key certificate from the JKS file

```
keytool -export -alias selfsigned -keystore keystore.jks -rfc -file publickey.cert
```

Read the certificate file from Java app:

```
// Use file stream to load from file system or class.getResourceAsStream to load from classpath             
InputStream readStream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("publickey.cert");

CertificateFactory f = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

//Certificate certificate = f.generateCertificate(readStream);
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)f.generateCertificate(readStream);

publicKey = certificate.getPublicKey();

readStream.close();
```

Verify signature with public key and jjwt

```
Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(publicKey).parseClaimsJws(accessToken).getBody();
```

The above code throws this exception:

```
io.jsonwebtoken.SignatureException: Unable to verify RSA signature using configured PublicKey. Signature length not correct: got 256 but was expecting 1369
```

Am I doing it right?

Comment: You shouldn't need to export anything. The digital signature should include certificate of the signer, and that includes its public key.

Comment: @EJP I cant trust the signer. So, I've to make sure its indeed signed with same key I hold

Comment: No, you have to make sure the *entire certificate* is the same, and trusted. After that it doesn't matter where you get the public key from.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, I was trying to verify signature with a wrong certificate (Keycloak JBOSS), but actually the access tokens were signed with the key from Realm. I had to create a certificate file from Realm -> Key -> RSA -> Certificate (not by generating it from the keystore JKS configured in Keycloak Jboss)

Answer (score 0):

It should work , I tried generating the same set of keys/certificate and validating it (I used Bouncy Castle)

```
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.X509CertificateObject;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemObject;
import org.bouncycastle.util.io.pem.PemReader;

import java.io.*;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.CertificateFactory;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.Enumeration;
public class CertTest {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
    try (Reader readStream = new FileReader("publickey.cert")){
      PemReader reader = new PemReader(readStream);
      CertificateFactory certFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
      PemObject pemObject = reader.readPemObject();
      X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)certFactory.generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(pemObject.getContent()));
      System.out.println(cert.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm());
    }
  }
}
```

Prints : RSA

Comment: Yes, it should work. Please see my answer. Thanks anyway!